# League of Legends Technology Level

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legends (Mostly in the lore) there are multiple different cities, all with different levels of technology.

Some champions use guns, some use swords, others magic.

Just how prevalent is technology in League of Legends?  It seems as though in any rational scenario a gun or magic would defeat blades, yet the characters ignore technology coming from places such as Zaun or Piltover.  Is this because they would not know of it, choose not to use it, or plain think a good old stick n' shield is better?  What would prevent some of the more advanced cities from taking over the other ones with weapons of advanced power?

What stops technology from being an end-all in League of Legends?

Comment: The problem you describe - being able to use magic and having technology, yet fighting with swords, is some pretty elemental problem in many fantasy settings, like Final Fantasy and other games. It's hardly possible to explain, so I'd just take that one thing as a given fact.

Comment: Agreed, (afaik) there is no in-lore explanation, so any answers would be speculative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far as I know this is never explained, however it is possible to explain.

The people in LoL are super-human. They can get shot multiple times and shrug it off, they can leap half way across the map, they can spin along with their sword out, etc.

In that situation the advantage of technology is much reduced. Magic is just as strong as technology, a super-human archer gets extra advantages of reflexes and strength that don't help the gunner, etc. The bows themselves may well be mystical artifacts or enchanted, or otherwise enhanced as well.

In our world guns have a big advantage, but in a world of super-humans and active magic that is not the case.

Comment: Also a sword is much better thana gun/bow/crossbow/... in close combat(because you can theoretically strike more often/precise).If you feel more comfortable fighting with a sword or a dagger AND you are some sort of superhuman that can take some shots you can just  grab this meele weapon and smash.